# How to jump to another page with pageview flutter

Tags: flutter, navigation

Hello I tried to jump to my second page tab if I press on a button on my first Page tab. Currently I know only call route of my seconde page widget but bottomnavbar isn't present... I don't know how to call my parent widget from my first page tab to jump to the seconde page tab.

```
  class Parent  {

  int bottomSelectedIndex = 0;

  List<BottomNavigationBarItem> buildBottomNavBarItems() {
    return [
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: new Icon(Icons.home),
          title: new Text('First')
      ),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
        icon: new Icon(Icons.search),
        title: new Text('Second'),
      ),

    ];
  }

  PageController pageController = PageController(
    initialPage: 0,
    keepPage: true,
  );

  Widget buildPageView() {
    return PageView(
      controller: pageController,
      onPageChanged: (index) {
        pageChanged(index);
      },
      children: <Widget>[
        First(),
        Second(),

      ],
    );
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  void pageChanged(int index) {
    setState(() {
      bottomSelectedIndex = index;
    });
  }

  void bottomTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {
      bottomSelectedIndex = index;
      pageController.animateToPage(index, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500), curve: Curves.ease);
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: buildPageView(),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        currentIndex: bottomSelectedIndex,
        onTap: (index) {
          bottomTapped(index);
        },
        items: buildBottomNavBarItems(),
      ),
    );
  }
  }
```

---

```
  class first {
        return Container(
    // here a pressbutton for jump to the second widget
        );

    }

----------------------------------------------------------


    class second
        return Container(

        );
    }
```

Comment: Hi can you be more specific what are you looking for? and what is the issue your facing. If there is any error log then do post that too.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

You can use this:

```
void onAddButtonTapped(int index) {

  // use this to animate to the page
  pageController.animateToPage(index);

  // or this to jump to it without animating
  pageController.jumpToPage(index);
}
```

Pass the function as params:

```
class first {
  final void Function(int) onAddButtonTapped;

        return Container(
// call it here onAddButtonTapped(2);
        );

    }

class Second {
  final void Function(int) onAddButtonTapped;

        return Container(
        );

    }
```

```
children: <Widget>[
        First(onAddButtonTapped),
        Second(onAddButtonTapped),
      ],
```

Comment: Thank you, but if I understand I can call onAddButtonTapped() only if I am in my parent widget with Pagecontroller declared. My problem is that I don't know how to call this new page from a child page.

Comment: Thank you it works :) but have you an idea if onButtonPressed comes from a widget who isn't in  PageView() [ ]  I have an other stfl widget I open with routes, and onPressed I want close this widget and jump to the second page :) I understand the pass of the callback but I don't understand how I can call this callback in this case

Comment: You can upvote the answer since it works then you can ask about another question!

Comment: it's an old one but saved my day! thanks :)

Answer (score 20):

You can pass a callback to your first widget and call that when the button is pressed, so you can change the page in the parent widget.
Something like this:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Test',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Parent(),
    );
  }
}

class Parent extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ParentState createState() => _ParentState();
}

class _ParentState extends State<Parent> {
  int bottomSelectedIndex = 0;

  List<BottomNavigationBarItem> buildBottomNavBarItems() {
    return [
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: new Icon(Icons.home), title: new Text('First')),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
        icon: new Icon(Icons.search),
        title: new Text('Second'),
      ),
    ];
  }

  PageController pageController = PageController(
    initialPage: 0,
    keepPage: true,
  );

  Widget buildPageView() {
    return PageView(
      controller: pageController,
      onPageChanged: (index) {
        pageChanged(index);
      },
      children: <Widget>[
        FirstWidget(
          onButtonPressed: () => pageController.animateToPage(
                1,
                duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300),
                curve: Curves.linear,
              ),
        ),
        SecondWidget(),
      ],
    );
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  void pageChanged(int index) {
    setState(() {
      bottomSelectedIndex = index;
    });
  }

  void bottomTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {
      bottomSelectedIndex = index;
      pageController.animateToPage(index,
          duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500), curve: Curves.ease);
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Test'),
      ),
      body: buildPageView(),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        currentIndex: bottomSelectedIndex,
        onTap: (index) {
          bottomTapped(index);
        },
        items: buildBottomNavBarItems(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class FirstWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final VoidCallback onButtonPressed;

  FirstWidget({@required this.onButtonPressed});

  @override
  _FirstWidgetState createState() => _FirstWidgetState();
}

class _FirstWidgetState extends State<FirstWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.red,
      child: Center(
        child: FlatButton(
          onPressed: widget.onButtonPressed,
          child: Text('Go to second page'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


class SecondWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(color: Colors.green);
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried but onButtonPressed isn't recognize... I'm very noob ^^ I think I don't understand how to use callback

Comment: What error is giving you? Have you declared the property in your First class? Have you added a constructor? First is a Stateless or Stateful Widget? 'VoidCallback' is just an alias for 'void Function()', you pass a function that can be called whenever you want.

Comment: undefined name 'onButtonPressed'  with the line onPressed: onButtonPressed,  I follow the exemple with call back in the constructor, first is a stfl widget.

Comment: I updated the answer converting First to a stateful widget, the callback needs to be on the widget and not in the state.

Comment: What if I need to add another button too. Like in my case 'Next' and 'Previous' buttons.. ? @LorenzOliveto

Comment: @Joe you can still use pageController.animateToPage(...) giving the page you want to scroll to as a parameter

Comment: Yes your code is working and it guided me to find solution which I'm looking for days to add two buttons in the child.