# Bottom Navigation Bar disappears when I navigate to other pages by clicking on Flat Button inside Scaffold

Tags: flutter, bottomnavigationview, flutter-navigation, flutter-bottomnavigation

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: MyNavigationBar(),
    );
  }
}

class MyNavigationBar extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyNavigationBarState createState() => _MyNavigationBarState();
}

class _MyNavigationBarState extends State<MyNavigationBar> {

  int _currentIndex = 0;

// all pages 
  final List<Widget> _children = [
    ListScreen(),
    HomaPage(),
    FourthScreen(),
    ThirdScreen(),
  ];

  void OnTappedBar(int index){
    setState(() {
      _currentIndex = index;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: _children[_currentIndex],
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
        selectedItemColor: Colors.black,
        unselectedItemColor: Colors.grey,
        onTap: OnTappedBar,
        currentIndex: _currentIndex,
        items: [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.home), title: Text("accueil")),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.search), title: Text("recherche")),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.calendar_today), title: Text("Mess Pass")),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.person), title: Text("Mon Profil")),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Please! can anyone tell me how the bottomNavigationBar appears on all pages.

When I click on the Flat button in Scaffold on any page then the bottom app bar is hidden, but when I use the bottom app bar items to navigate on other pages then the bottom app bar does not disappear. So how can i fix this. I want that the bottom app bar is present on all the pages even I used buttons in the scaffold to navigate or bottom app bar items???

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/persistent_bottom_nav_bar

Comment: Are you using `Navigator` inside `FlatButton's` `onPressed` method?

Comment: @_ASAD HAMEED yes I use Navigator

Comment: Edited my answer and added more details for implementation. Give it a try :)

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are calling 'Navigator.push()' inside `FlatButton's` `onPressed` method.

What's happening here is that when you call `Navigator.push()` the screen with `BottomNavigationBar` hides under the new screen, or goes down in the `ScreenStack`(a made-up term).

What you should do instead is use `PageController` to navigate to different pages inside the Flatbutton's onPressed.

```
pageController.animateToPage(index);
```

See this answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/56540176/10285344

In order to customise your current implementation to fit your requirement, I would suggest you the following changes.

You should either use PageView to achieve this, because it provides you a `controller` to switch between pages.

**For your case**
If you do not want to use `PageView` for some reason, I would recommend the following workaround I used in one of my recent projects I use `Provider` to switch between `Screens` without using `Navigator` or `PageView`.

You'll need `Provider` package for this customisation.
https://pub.dev/packages/provider/install

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: ChangeNotifierProvider<ValueNotifier<int>>.value(
        value: ValueNotifier<int>(0), //PageIndex is set to 0 to open first when when the app launches
        child:  MyNavigationBar(),
      ),

    );
  }
}


class MyNavigationBar extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyNavigationBarState createState() => _MyNavigationBarState();
}

class _MyNavigationBarState extends State<MyNavigationBar> {


// all pages 
  final List<Widget> _children = [
    ListScreen(),
    HomaPage(),
    FourthScreen(),
    ThirdScreen(),
  ];

  void OnTappedBar(int index){
    Provider.of<ValueNotifier<int>>(context, listen: false).value = index;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: _children[Provider.of<ValueNotifier<int>>(context).value],
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
        selectedItemColor: Colors.black,
        unselectedItemColor: Colors.grey,
        onTap: OnTappedBar,
        currentIndex: Provider.of<ValueNotifier<int>>(context).value,,
        items: [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.home), title: Text("accueil")),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.search), title: Text("recherche")),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.calendar_today), title: Text("Mess Pass")),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.person), title: Text("Mon Profil")),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

How to switch to different page from inside of a page?

```
class ListScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ListScreenState createState() => _ListScreenState();
}

class _ListScreenState extends State<ListScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(child: FlatButton(
        child: Text('Switch To HomePage'),
        onPressed: (){

          Provider.of<ValueNotifier<int>>(context, listen: false).value = 1;
        },
      ),),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Under the FlatButton i used Navigator.pushReplacement

Comment: I did not declare the bottom Navigation Bar on other pages. I declare the Bottom Navigation Bar in only the main Page.

Comment: First of all, let's remove the confusion by using the work **Screen** for the scaffold where  `bottomNavigationBar` is implemented and **Page** for the widgets inside of a `PageView`.

You need to remove `Navigator.pushReplacement()` since it replace the screen with the `bottomNavigationBar`. 

I will add more details to my answer on how you can customise your current code to fir the requirement.

Comment: @BilalAhmad I have added details customisation in the answer. I should definitely work since I'm myself using this approach in my production app.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this package [persistent_bottom_nav_bar](https://pub.dev/packages/persistent_bottom_nav_bar) to achieve this kind of functionality

Comment: The package you recommended is great and gave me a great idea for my app, but I think Bilal just wants to switch between pages from within the pages that are inside the scope of the nav bar.

Answer (score 2):

By default, Bottom navigation bar not persistent in MaterialApp.
You can achieve this using CupertinoTabScaffold, but not with Material concepts.

There is workaround for the same in Material and Scaffold by implementing custom Navigator for your tabs and bottom navigation. But here we need to handle many cases for Push/Pop navigators.

Currently, I'm using this custom navigator approach for my persistant bottom navigation use case, Will let you know once completed my stuff.

meanwhile some resources that helped me proceed

https://codewithandrea.com/articles/multiple-navigators-bottom-navigation-bar/
https://medium.com/@theboringdeveloper/common-bottom-navigation-bar-flutter-e3693305d2d