# how to change the display order of pageview pages - Flutter

Tags: flutter

And that I want to change the display order of a page according to the user's action. If he clicks on button 1, the red page is displayed first, if he clicks on button 2, the yellow page is displayed first.

How can I change the order of the pages?

would it be correct for me to use pageview.builder?

```dart
class PageViewTest extends StatefulWidget {
  const PageViewTest({super.key});

  @override
  State<PageViewTest> createState() => _PageViewTestState();
}

class _PageViewTestState extends State<PageViewTest> {
  final _pageController = PageController();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return PageView(
      controller: _pageController,
      children: [
        Column(
          children: [
            TextButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  //show container red with next page
                },
                child: const Text("Button 1")),
            TextButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  //show container yellow next page
                },
                child: const Text("Button 2")),
          ],
        ),
        Container(
          color: Colors.red,
        ),
        Container(
          color: Colors.yellow,
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56540074/how-to-jump-to-another-page-with-pageview-flutter your question is duplicated

Comment: I do not seek to jump to another page, but change the order of construction of the pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way,

```
class PageViewTest extends StatefulWidget {
  const PageViewTest({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _PageViewTestState createState() => _PageViewTestState();
}

class _PageViewTestState extends State<PageViewTest> {
  final _pageController = PageController();
  int _currentPageIndex = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return PageView.builder(
      controller: _pageController,
      itemCount: 2,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        switch (index) {
          case 0:
            return Column(
              children: [
                TextButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    setState(() {
                      _currentPageIndex = 1;
                    });
                  },
                  child: const Text("Button 1"),
                ),
                TextButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    setState(() {
                      _currentPageIndex = 2;
                    });
                  },
                  child: const Text("Button 2"),
                ),
              ],
            );
          case 1:
            return Container(
              color: Colors.red,
            );
          case 2:
            return Container(
              color: Colors.yellow,
            );
          default:
            return Container();
        }
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `PageView.builder` or normal `PageView` both will work.

As for the changing of pages you should use the `PageController` passed into your `PageView` and call `_pageController.animateToPage(pageNumber)` or `_pageController.jumpToPage(pageNumber)`, if you don't want animation,in your button.